# Characteristic polynomial of an $8 \times 8$ symmetric matrix with indeterminate entries related to octonionic multiplication

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, computational-geometry, octonions

I consider $1,i,j,k,l,m,n,o$ the standard basis of the (complexified if you like) octonions ($\mathbb{O}$ for the octonions).
Let $a = x_1.1 +\ldots + x_8.o$, $b = x_9.1+ \ldots + x_{16}.o$ and $c = x_{17}.1+ \ldots +x_{24}.o$, where $x_1, \ldots, x_{24}$ are indeterminates over the base field (say $\mathbb{C}$).

I denote by $L_a$ the $8 \times 8$ matrix which represents the left multiplication by $a$ in $\mathbb{O} \simeq \mathbb{C}^8$ and $R_a$ the $8 \times 8$ matrix which represents the right multiplication by $a$. Similar notations for $b$ and $c$. I would like to compute the characteristic polynomial of the symmetric matrix:
$$ S = \dfrac{1}{2}(R_a L_b L_c + {}^{t}(R_a L_b L_c)),$$
where ${}^{t} X$ is the transpose of $X$.

I have tried with Macaulay2 and this computation seems to be far beyond the possibilities my machine (which is supposed to be a quite powerful portable workstation).

A simple reforrmulation of the eigenvalue problem in a well-chosen basis (namely let $\mathbb{H}$ be the quaternionic subalgebra generated by $b$ and $c$, split $\mathbb{O}$ as $\mathbb{H} \bigoplus \mathbb{H}.e$, where $e$ is orthogonal to $\mathbb{H}$ and take a basis adapted to this decomposition) shows that:
$$ (T - \mathrm{Re}((bc)\overline{a}))^4 \ \textrm{divides} \ det(S- T.id),$$
where $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ is the real part of $z \in \mathbb{O}$.

I put $f(T) = \dfrac{det(S- T.id)}{(T - \mathrm{Re}((bc)\overline{a})^4}$. A vast number of computations over finite fields and specializing the $x_i$ to random values suggests that $f(T)$ is in fact a square, say $f(T) = g(T)^2$, where $g$ is a quadratic polynomial in $T$.

I would like to get a closed expression of $g(T)$. May it be a clean formula involving $a,b$ and $c$ or a dirty "in coordinates" polynomial. I would really appreciate any suggestion. I would also be interested in a theoretical argument which shows that $f(T)$ is indeed a square.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{O}$ be octonions and consider the linear map $L:\mathbb{O}\to\mathbb{O}$ defined by
$$
L(x) = (b(cx))a = R_aL_bL_c(x).
$$
One desires a formula for the characteristic polynomial of $S$, the *symmetric* part of $L$, i.e.,
$$
S(x) = \tfrac12\bigl(R_aL_bL_c + {}^t(R_aL_bL_c) \bigr).
$$
(I note that the OP seems to have inadvertently omitted the factor of $\tfrac12$ in the formula for $S$; this becomes apparent when one compares the claimed formula for the characteristic polynomial of $S$  when $a = b = c = 1$.)
This is equivalent to knowing the symmetric functions of the eigenvalues of the quadratic form
$$
Q(x) = L(x)\cdot x = (b(cx))a\cdot x
$$
relative to the quadratic form $Q_0(x) = x\cdot x$.

First, note that, if any of $a$, $b$ or $c$ vanishes, then, of course,
$L$ and $Q$ vanish identically, and all of the eigenvalues of $S$ are equal to zero. Thus, we can assume that none of $a$, $b$, or $c$ vanishes. Then, dividing by
$|abc|\not=0$, we can assume that $|a| = |b| = |c| = 1$.

In this case, since $L$, being a product of elements of $\mathrm{SO}(8)$, belongs to $\mathrm{SO}(8)$, it follows that $L$ is conjugate in $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ to an element of the maximal torus ${\mathrm{SO}(2)}^4$, i.e., a blocked diagonal matrix
where the diagonal elements are the $2$-by-$2$ rotation matrices $R(\theta_i)$ for $1\le i\le 4$.  The matrix $S$ (the symmetric part of $L$) is then diagonal with double eigenvalues $\cos(\theta_i)$, and hence the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is
$$
p(t) = (t-\cos\theta_1)^2(t-\cos\theta_2)^2(t-\cos\theta_3)^2(t-\cos\theta_4)^2.
$$
When $p(t)= t^8 + r_1\,t^7 + r_2\,t^6 + \cdots + r_8$, we have $p(t) = q(t)^2$ where
$$
q(t) = t^4 + \tfrac12\,r_1\,t^3 + \tfrac18(4r_2-{r_1}^2)\,t^2 + \cdots
$$
(I leave it to the interested reader to work out the formulae for the $t$ and constant coefficients of $q$ as polynomials in $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$).

Now, by a theorem of Dickson, $b$ and $c$ lie in a quaternion subalgebra $\mathbb{A}\subset\mathbb{O}$.  Also, we can write $a = \cos\theta\,a_0 + \sin\theta\, u$ where $a_0\in\mathbb{A}$ is a unit vector, $u\in\mathbb{A}^\perp$ is a unit octonion, and $0\le \theta\le \tfrac12\pi$.  [This expression for $a$ will be unique relative to $\mathbb{A}$ if $0<\theta<\tfrac12\pi$.]

In what follows, it will be useful to remember that elements of $\mathbb{O}$ satisfy $xy\cdot z = x\cdot z\bar y = y\cdot \bar x z$.  Recalling that $\mathrm{Re}(x) = x\cdot\mathbf{1}$ (where $\mathbf{1}\in\mathbb{O}$ is the multiplicative unit), these identities imply that $\mathrm{Re}(xy) = \mathrm{Re}(yx)$ and that $\mathrm{Re}\bigl(a(bc)\bigr) = \mathrm{Re}\bigl((ab)c\bigr)$, so that $\mathrm{Re}(abc)$ is unambiguous, even though $\mathbb{O}$ is not associative.  We also have
$$
\mathrm{Re}(abc) = \mathrm{Re}(bca) = \mathrm{Re}(cab) 
= \mathrm{Re}(\bar c\,\bar b\,\bar a),
$$
but note that $\mathrm{Re}(abc)\not=\mathrm{Re}(bac)$ in general.

While $\mathbb{O} = \mathbb{A}\oplus \mathbb{A} u$
(note the orthogonal direct sum) is not associative,
we have the product formula of Cayley and Dickson:
$$
(a+b\,u)(c+d\,u) = \bigl( ac - \bar d b\bigr) + (da + b\bar c)\,u
$$
for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{A}$.

Writing $x\in\mathbb{O}$ as $x = x_0 + x_1\,u$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{A}$
and using the Cayley-Dickson formula several times, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q(x) 
&=  (b(cx))a\cdot x = b(cx)\cdot x\bar a \\
&= b(c(x_0+x_1\,u))\cdot (x_0+x_1\,u)(\cos\theta\,\overline{a_0} -\sin\theta\,u)\\
&= \bigl(bcx_0 + (x_1cb)\,u\bigr)\cdot\bigl((\cos\theta\,x_0\overline{a_0}+\sin\theta\,x_1) + (\cos\theta\,x_1a_0-\sin\theta\,x_0)\,u\bigr)\\
&=\cos\theta\,bcx_0\cdot x_0\overline{a_0}
+ \sin\theta(bcx_0\cdot x_1-x_1cb\cdot x_0) + \cos\theta\,x_1cb\cdot x_1a_0\\
&= \cos\theta\,bcx_0\cdot x_0\overline{a_0}
+ \sin\theta(bcx_0-x_0\bar b\bar c)\cdot x_1 
+ \cos\theta\,x_1\cdot x_1a_0\bar b\bar c\\
&= \cos\theta\,bcx_0a_0\cdot x_0
+ \sin\theta(bcx_0-x_0\bar b\bar c)\cdot x_1 
+ x_1{\cdot}x_1\,\mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,a_0\bar b\bar c)
\end{aligned}
$$
(Note that I have used $x_1\cdot x_1a_0\bar b\bar c = \overline{x_1}x_1\cdot a_0\bar b\bar c = |x_1|^2 \mathrm{Re}(a_0\bar b\bar c)$.

This expression can be further simplified.  Since $b$ and $c$ are unit vectors in
$\mathbb{A}$, we can write $bc = w$, which implies that $b = w\bar c$ and hence that $\bar b\bar c = c\bar w\bar c$.  Making the substitution $x_0 = y_0\bar c$
and $x_1 = y_1\bar c$ then yields $Q_0(x) = |x_0|^2+|x_1|^2 = |y_0|^2+|y_1|^2$ while setting $v = \bar c a_0 c$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
Q(x) &= \cos\theta\,wy_0{\bar c}a_0 \cdot y_0\bar c
+ \sin\theta\,(wy_0-y_0\bar w)\cdot y_1 
+ |y_1|^2\,\mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,a_0\bar b\bar c)\\
& = \cos\theta\,wy_0v \cdot y_0
+ \sin\theta\,(wy_0-y_0\bar w)\cdot y_1 
+ |y_1|^2\,\mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,v\bar w)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using this reduced form, it is straightforward to compute that the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is
$$
\bigl(t-\mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,v\bar w)\bigr)^4
\bigl(t^2-2\cos\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)\mathrm{Re}(w)\,t
+ \cos^2\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)^2w\bar w - |\mathrm{Im}(w)|^2\bigr)^2,
$$
which can also be written as
$$
\bigl(t-\mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,v\bar w)\bigr)^4
\bigl((t-\cos\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)\mathrm{Re}(w))^2
- |\mathrm{Im}(w)|^2(1-\cos^2\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)^2)\bigr)^2,
$$
so that its roots are $t = \mathrm{Re}(\cos\theta\,v\bar w)$ with multiplicity $4$
and
$$
t = \cos\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)\mathrm{Re}(w)
\pm |\mathrm{Im}(w)|\bigl(1-\cos^2\theta\,\mathrm{Re}(v)^2)^{1/2},
$$
each with multiplicity $2$.

Finally, tracing back through the definitions and normalizations, we see that the characteristic polynomial of $S$ can be written in the form
$$
\bigl(t-\mathrm{Re}(a\bar b\bar c)\bigr)^4
\bigl(\bigl(t-\mathrm{Re}(a)\,\mathrm{Re}(bc)\bigr)^2-\mathrm{Im}(a)^2\,\mathrm{Im}(bc)^2\bigr)^2.
$$

**Note on a computation:** Since the OP asked, here is a bit of
detail of the computation of the characteristic polynomial.

We can choose a basis of $\mathbb{A}\simeq\mathbb{H}$ as $(\bf{1},\bf{i},\bf{j},\bf{k})$
in such a way that $w = w_0\,{\bf{1}}+w_1\,\bf{i}$ while $v = v_0\,{\bf{1}}+v_1\,{\bf{i}}+v_2\,{\bf{j}}+v_3\,{\bf{k}}$.  Now write out $y_0$
in the orthonormal basis $(\bf{1},\bf{i},\bf{j},\bf{k})$ and $y_1$
in the orthonormal basis $(-\bf{i},\bf{1},\bf{j},\bf{k})$.

Set $\lambda_1 = c(v_{{0}}w_{{0}}{-}v_{{1}}w_{{1}})$ and $\lambda_2=c(v_{{0}}w_{{0}}{+}v_{{1}}w_{{1}})$ where $c = \cos\theta$ and $s=\sin\theta$
(to make the matrix below more readable).  Then the matrix of
the quadratic form $Q$ in this basis is
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccccccc} 
\lambda_1&0&-cw_{{1}}v_{{3}}&cw_{{1}}v_{{2}}&sw_{{1}}&0&0&0\\
0&\lambda_1&-cw_{{1}}v_{{2}}&-cw_{{1}}v_{{3}}&0&sw_{{1}}&0&0\\
-cw_{{1}}v_{{3}}&-cw_{{1}}v_{{2}}&\lambda_2&0&0&0&0&0\\
cw_{{1}}v_{{2}}&-cw_{{1}}v_{{3}}&0&\lambda_2&0&0&0&0\\ 
sw_{{1}}&0&0&0&\lambda_2&0&0&0\\ 
0&sw_{{1}}&0&0&0&\lambda_2&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&\lambda_2&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\lambda_2
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
Now tell MAPLE to compute the characteristic polynomial of this matrix and tell it to factor the result.  (I confess that it's a bit surprising that $\lambda_2$ turns out to be a root of multiplicity $4$ instead of just $2$. I don't have a 'theoretical' understanding of this. Looking at the matrix, you can see that by choosing the basis of $\mathbb{A}$ a bit more carefully, you could arrange that $v_2=0$, and that makes it clear that the characteristic polynomial will be a square, but we knew that already.)

Comment: Great, I feel somehow comforted that you found out the characteristic polynomial with Maple. Computing directly the matrix of $S$ wia the splitting $\mathbb{O} = \mathbb{H} \oplus \mathbb{H}.e$, I get the following: $\dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} R_{a_0} L_b L_c + {}^{t}(R_{a_0} L_b L_c) & P \\ {}^{t} P & 2\mathrm{Re}(bc \overline{a}) \end{pmatrix}$, where $P = R_{a_1} {}^{t} L_c {}^{t} L_b - R_{a_1}{}^{t} L_c R_{b}$ and $a = a_0 + a_1.e$.

Comment: Up to a change of coordinates, this seems to be exactly the same matrix as for the quadratic form $Q$ you exhibited. I was more or less able to understand that $2 \mathrm{Re}(bc\overline{a})$ is an eigenvalue of even multiplicity (though $4$ was alos a big surprise for me). But I couldn't get my hands on the missing part of the characterisitic polynomial. I thought that perhaps there is theoretical way to do it. Looking at the first version of your answer, I had the impression you knew one.

Comment: Anyway, even if you found it with Maple, this is very interesting for me and a nice answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Libli: If you do go ahead and choose the basis of $\mathbb{A}$ so that $v_2=0$, then the matrix I wrote down above clearly can be decomposed as the orthogonal direct sum of two copies of the same $3$-by-$3$ symmetric matrix plus a $2$-by-$2$ matrix that is a multiple of the identity. Since one can easily compute the characteristic polynomial of the $3$-by-$3$ matrix by hand, the use of MAPLE  was not actually necessary. Thus, one could do the computation by hand, but I felt it was better to state that I used MAPLE, since I didn't see the by-hand argument until I used MAPLE to get the result.